repeating-linear-gradient breaks in the middle of page on mobile device
I want to have a background-image: repeating-linear-gradient so that my page will look like a notebook page. Let's consider the following HTML as a ground for the question:


.box {
  background-color: #fffec1;
  height: 100vh;
}
.notebook {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(transparent 0px 20px, rgba(0, 45, 112, 0.356) 20px 21px);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box notebook">
        <!-- optionally long content -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>



The resulting page looks like this:

On my real web page, this background applies to a HTML <section> which can get quite long especially on a mobile device.
On a PC it looks good. The problem is that on a mobile device, for some reason, the repeating-linear-gradient stops appearing at a certain point. This is how it actually looks like on a mobile device:

Now, if I add another pixel in the last color-stop (22px instead of 21px), like this:
 background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(transparent 0px 20px, rgba(0, 45, 112, 0.356) 20px 22px);

Then, I notice that the repeating-linear-gradient gets longer than it was with 21px, but still doesn't make it till the end:

If I increase it to 23px, then it gets all the way to the end:

Another thing that I've noticed that may be related to the problem is that the thickness of the lines are pretty inconsistent. Look at this for example:

you can see that some lines are thicker than others.
Tried my best to understand why this happens. Please help

You are restricting the viewport height with height: 100vh;, so if the textcontent's height is rendered larger than a full viewport (which it will often do on a mobile device, as the viewport is much smaller in both width and height), it will just overflow from the box that is restricted to 100vh, which contains your background.
